# how to use a resourcefile item in my aspx file?

Tags: asp.net

this is my code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<%$ Resources:WebsiteResource, linkUrl %>">..</a>
```

but i get this error that this is not allowed, that i have to use a literal.
But this:

```
   <a target="_blank" href="<asp:literal runat="server" id="Literal1"></asp:literal>">..</a>
```

leads to this:

```
<a href=""<asp:literal" id="ctl00_ctl00_CPHMainSection_CPH_LeftSection_Literal1" target="_blank"></asp:literal>">
```

also tried this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<%<asp:literal runat="server" id="Literal1"></asp:literal> %>">
```

but didn't work either...

Comment: Have you added the resource file to your project? Here's a good reference that may help answer questions you have. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: yes it is. Somewhere else in the code, i can do the first code, but then at the 'text' property of a server control.

Comment: and typing that, gave me the answer: i had to do this: <a runat="server"> and make it a server control!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a id="something" runat="server" target="_blank" href="<%$ Resources:WebsiteResource, linkUrl %>">..</a>
```

put **runat="server"** will make the magic. Because asp will ignore none server side control